# Are direction cosines scalar or vector quantities, and why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

As seen highlighted below ([from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine#Three-dimensional_Cartesian_coordinates)), the direction cosines are the ratio of the dot product of a vector with the standard basis vectors, resulting in scalars, to the magnitude of the vector, which is a scalar. A scalar divided by a scalar results in a scalar. Therefore, the direction cosines of a vector are scalar quantities, is that correct?
[image]

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Yes. What is confusing?

Comment: The formulas say it clearly, scalars. Why ? Because they are projection ratios.

Comment: @Clayton I'm trying to understand an operation: multiplying the vector components of a vector by the direction cosines of a vector area $\vec A=A \hat n$. It seems that this should result in a vector since direction cosines are scalars. If that is true, then I'm trying to understand how I would notate this operation in both matrix and tensor (indicial) notations.